# Selenium Firefox webdriverdriver: extension (IETab v2) configurations - Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, firefox-addon

Python v2.7 and Selenium I guess it is v2.49 (current last version)

I was able to add the extension (IETab V2):

```
profile=FirefoxProfile(profilePath)
profile.add_extension(extension=extensionPath)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Im normally able to configure the extension (when Im not using the browser through webdriver) and the configurations are there everytime I open the browser (Im setting the websites to be opened with IETab). However, when I open the browser through webdriver although the extension is there I lose the configurations.

Any idea how to keep the extensions configs when loading the browser through webdriver?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most firefox extensions keep their settings in the profile settings. You can access those by typing about:config in your url bar. Find the corresponding settings and set them manually on your FirefoxProfile instance. If there's too many settings, search for prefs.js in your firefox profile directory. That's a snapshot of the settings in plain text from the last time you closed the browser.